# Inadvertently entered a password into the BIOS and now I can't use my laptop

Tags: bios, passwords

I was trying to fix my computer and I was doing all sorts of stuff in the BIOS when I ended up putting a password on my system. Now when I turn my laptop on, it asks for a password right away before I can even hold shift down to get to the GRUB menu. Does anyone know if I can fix this?

Comment: Possibly a BIOS reset will help (bridge a jumper as indicated in your laptop manual, if possible?) BIOS passwords are asked for before even GRUB is loaded, so Shift won't do anything.

Comment: You need to at least let us know your laptop model for a small change someone knows the default service password for it.

Comment: If you are out of waranty and know what you are doing: open the laptop, remove the bios battery, wait a day, put it back and reassemble your laptop. If you dont know what you are doing or are still in waranty, just call the service. In any case you will lose all your BIOS-Settings

Answer (score 1):

Once you find your BIOS battery (looks like a large watch battery), you can remove it and short the connections with something metal (NONMAGNETIC). By doing this will most often reset the BIOS back to it's factory settings.

Comment: "short" it?  I don't think that sounds like a good idea.  Look up the proper process for you Motherboard.  It usually invovles removing the CMOS batter and setting a jumper to a paricular setting or some other action.  If THAT is what Kobatls meant by "short" then by all means.  Otherwise steer well clear of that.

Comment: "Setting a Jumper" = Flathead Screwdriver to battery terminals

Comment: Oh. Remove the power cord and press your on button for a second before doing anything. It will discharge any capacitors

Comment: Better :)  Still I don't advise the screw driver method... damn MB comes with the jumper AND a manual.  Use them both :)

Comment: If the motherboard has a jumper and you're able to find it then sure, that is the preferred route. However, not all motherboards have a jumper to clear the CMOS/BIOS. Instead of shorting it, you could just leave the battery out overnight and it would essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Sounds MUCH safer for a novice :)